# Why isn't ||= a valid operator?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

Why doesn't C have a ||= operator, or any other language for that matter? Is there some technical reason, or is it for language aesthetics?

*Edit* Apparently Perl and Ruby have this, I didn't know that when asking.

Comment: Though the Q maybe language agnostic, the answer might not be.

Comment: Is this supposedly a comparison or assignment operator?

Comment: "Why doesn't C have a ||= operator, or any other language for that matter?" False premise. Perl and Ruby (probably others too) have `||=`.

Comment: @OrionRogue, in Ruby `x ||= y` is equivalent to `x = x || y` where `||` is logical `or`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C this operator would be utterly nonsense. Think about the following example:

```
char ind = 0;
ind |= 1;
ind |= 0;
// ind is still 1
```

This is doing exactly what `||=` would achieve. For all types that are non-castable to bool this would be stupid anyways. Am I missing something?

In all other programming languages without type inference this operator would only be valid for booleans.

Answer (score 1):

I would venture to guess it wasn't included in c ( unlike |= ) because it wouldn't make a lot of since in 99% of circumstances.  || is a Boolean operator.  While zero and not zero pass for Booleans in the language, what should the assignment to an integer or pointer of true actually be.  1, -1, 42?  It introduces an awful lot ambiguity for not much benefit.